# using imextendedmax in matlab 2013

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm using Matlab 2013  , I want to use immextendedmax function , for some pictures It's okay but for some pictures error comes  :

```
" Error using imageDisplayValidateParams>validateCData (line 121)
 If input is logical (binary), it must be two-dimensional. "


   I = imread('2.jpg');
   BW = imextendedmax(I,80);
   imshow(I), figure, imshow(BW)
```

I read  description in this link http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imextendedmax.html?nocookie=true 
but I can't understand why this error comes .

Comment: What is the size and class of `I`? `class(I)` and `size(I)` returns this information.

Comment: size(I) is 290 400 3    @Daniel

Comment: Sound like this function don't like 3D array.

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau documentation says it is possible. It's a standard coloured image.

Comment: @N_93: I am unable to reproduce the issue with Matlab 2013a, could you upload your image?

Comment: @Daniel I understand that matrix must be  two-dimensional and I use im2bw to convert the matrix  here is the image http://uploadkon.ir/fl/d/MTEyMzk%3D

Comment: The problem isn't with imextendedmax, but with imshow. He didn't provide the full error. In case of logical image, imshow cannot use 3D.

Comment: So you can just do : imshow(BW(:,:,1)); or 2 or 3. Because maybe your conn change between channel depending on your parameter.

Comment: I think You are right @AlexandreBizeau